# Find Attribute Value in XML file VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a following details included xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LoadSurveyValues>
  <LoadSurvey timeStamp="18/12/2015 11:13:02" saveMode="SnapShot">
    <Date Date="18/12/2015 00:00:00">
      <ParamValues Type="ActiveTotalImport" Unit="kWh">
        <SipValues Time="00:15" ParamValue="0" />
        <SipValues Time="00:30" ParamValue="0" />
        <SipValues Time="00:45" ParamValue="0" />
        <SipValues Time="01:00" ParamValue="0" />
        <SipValues Time="01:15" ParamValue="0.5" />
        <SipValues Time="01:30" ParamValue="0.1" />
        <SipValues Time="01:45" ParamValue="0" />
        <SipValues Time="02:00" ParamValue="0" />
        <SipValues Time="02:15" ParamValue="0" />
        <SipValues Time="02:30" ParamValue="0" />
```

and so on

I want to find out "ParamValue" attribute value in "Date" date 18/12/2015, "ParamValues" type ActiveTotalImport" and "SipValue" time 01:15. That result should be 0.5.

These are codes I tried in VB.net using listboxes.

```
  Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("meter 01.xml")
  If ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        If ListBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            If ListBox3.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then

                If xr.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element And xr = ListBox1.SelectedIndex And xr = ListBox2.SelectedIndex And xr = ListBox3.SelectedIndex Then

                    ListBox4.Items.Add(xr.GetAttribute(1))

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

ListBox1 has selected 18/12/2015 00:00:00 value, ListBox2 has selected ActiveTotalImport value and ListBox3 has selected 01:15 value. Therefore the result is adding to the ListBox4 which is 0.5 value. But this code is not working please help me solve it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim survey As XElement = doc.Descendants("LoadSurvey").Where(Function(x) x.Attribute("timeStamp").Value = "18/12/2015 11:13:02").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ParamValue As String = survey.Descendants("SipValues").Where(Function(x) x.Attribute("Time").Value = "01:15").Select(Function(y) y.Attribute("ParamValue")).FirstOrDefault()
    End Sub

End Module
```